# Will I use more battery if I set a repeating alarm for every 10 minutes from now on instead of setting a new single alarm each time?

Tags: android

Will I use more battery if I set a repeating alarm for every 10 minutes from now on instead of setting a new single alarm each time?

Case A:
I set an alarm via alarm manager for 10 minutes later from now, and then set interval 10 minutes, so it is supposed to fire off every 10 minutes from now on.

Case B:
I set a single alarm via alarm manager for 10 minutes later from now, and then when it fires off, I call the same method to set the same alarm for 10 minutes after.

Will case A waste more battery than case B.

```
public static void executeTaskAfterXMinutes(Context context, int minutes) {

    long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    long certainAmountOfMinutesLater = ((long) minutes * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS) + now;

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TaskReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1300, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setExact(...
    alarmManager.setRepeating(...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referencing `setExact()`, I assume that you are thinking about doing this on API Level 19+.

In that case, `setRepeating()` will be more efficient than doing your own repeating using `setExact()`, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, because `setRepeating()` is inexact on API Level 19+ if your `targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher. Allowing Android to coalesce events through inexact alarms can reduce power drain.

Even for cases where `setRepeating()` is exact (API Level 18 and below, or `targetSdkVersion` 18 or below), I would expect that `setRepeating()` would be at least as efficient as `set()`/`setExact()`. It might even be a bit more efficient, as Android knows further in advance when your events should occur and might move the inexact events of other apps to the times you request. With `set()`/`setExact()`, Android only knows one future event.

Comment: @J.K.: Well, I would recommend `setInexactRepeating()`, to be more explicit about the fact that this is inexact, and so you get inexact behavior on older devices. Given the choice between `setExact()` and `setRepeating()`, I would use `setRepeating()`.

Comment: Thank You! You have always been very helpful

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to allow Android to coalesce events through inexact alarms. Exact alarms are probably more wall-clock aligned, so pulling all alarms toward a wall-clock alignment seems very inefficient.

Comment: @JavaChipMocha: It will be more efficient from a battery standpoint. Google has done [conference presentations on this point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzSKIpJepUw) -- you're welcome to provide similar levels of evidence in favor of your viewpoint. Moreover, the drive is to get all recurring alarms to be inexact (directly or via layers like `JobScheduler`), which will reduce the "wall-clock alignment" issue that you cite.